# Mailchimp edit table cell background color

Tags: mailchimp

Is there any logical way to change the background colour for a table cell in a repeatable region in mailchimp? Here is my code, I don't see any options in mailchimp with the custom template build.

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="20" mc:repeatable="product" mc:variant="content1">
         <tbody>
              <tr>
                 <td align="center" bgcolor="#ff0000" valign="middle" mc:edit="playlist"><h2>Playlist</h2>
                   <h3>Check out this playlist!</h3>
                    <h4><a href="#">FOLLOW</a></h4></td>
              </tr>
         </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a similar issue today. Here's a possible solution:

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing="20" mc:repeatable="product" mc:variant="red">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#ff0000" valign="middle" mc:edit="playlist">
        <h2>Playlist</h2>
        <h3>Check out this playlist!</h3>
        <h4><a href="#">FOLLOW</a></h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="20" mc:repeatable="product" mc:variant="green">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#00ff00" valign="middle" mc:edit="playlist">
        <h2>Playlist</h2>
        <h3>Check out this playlist!</h3>
        <h4><a href="#">FOLLOW</a></h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table width="100%" cellspacing="20" mc:repeatable="product" mc:variant="blue">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" bgcolor="#0000ff" valign="middle" mc:edit="playlist">
        <h2>Playlist</h2>
        <h3>Check out this playlist!</h3>
        <h4><a href="#">FOLLOW</a></h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

When you've imported this into your template, create a campaign and on the design page you'll have a dropdown with the different colour options. Make any h2s, h3s etc editable by adding mc:edit.

Comment: Awesome sounds like this is exactly what we need.